# Redirect Loops in Switch Case with header(location)

Tags: php, redirect, switch-statement

```
<?php

$rexgeoip = new RexGeoIp;
$iso = strtoupper( $rexgeoip->getCountryIso() );


    switch ($iso) {
        case 'DE':
                header("Location: http://www.domain.de/en/",TRUE,301);
            break;

        case 'AT':
                header("Location: http://www.domain.de",TRUE,301);
             break;

        case 'CH':
                header("Location: http://www.domain.de",TRUE,301);
             break;

        default:
                header("Location: http://www.domain.de/en/",TRUE,301);
        break;
    }
}

echo "<!-- your iso is $iso -->";

?>
```

This is my code which redirects to the corresponding domain path. 
I changed the DE case to /en because I'm in Germany and want to test the redirect.
But every time I hit with DE ISO I get a "to many redirects" timeout. This also happens if I connect via a web-proxy from US or Asia.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You're probably falling in an infinite loop because this code that you posted is hosted on your /en page or so => You're redirected to it, then it tests your region and tries to redirect, and so on...

Comment: Is this script by chance on saved as the index on either `http://www.domain.de/en/` or `http://www.domain.de/`

Comment: Its on both, the same header get called on both languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `de` to the path and don't redirect in the script which is responsible for `http://www.domain.de/de/` or for `http://www.domain.de/en/`:

```
<?php

$rexgeoip = new RexGeoIp;
$iso = strtoupper( $rexgeoip->getCountryIso() );


switch ($iso) {
    case 'DE':
            header("Location: http://www.domain.de/en/",TRUE,301);
            exit;
        break;

    case 'AT':
            header("Location: http://www.domain.de/de/",TRUE,301);
            exit;
         break;

    case 'CH':
            header("Location: http://www.domain.de/de/",TRUE,301);
            exit;                 
         break;

    default:
            header("Location: http://www.domain.de/en/",TRUE,301);
            exit;
    break;
  }
}

echo "Script never gets here";

?>
```

Comment: Either this, or don't redirect if you already are on the page you are redirecting to.